# Gulp doesn't create a "dist" folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

I have two different projects. Both have a `gulpfile.js`, `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. The folders structure is absolutely identical.

When I start gulp in the first project's folder, it goes ok: I receive a dist folder with everything inside.

But when I try this in the second one, it doesn't. The dist folder just isn't created. And I just receive the message "Cannot GET /".

My project structure:

```
project root
    #src
        fonts
        img
        js
            script.js (empty)
        scss
            style.scss (empty)
        index.html (includes <body> tag)
    node_modules
    gulpfile.js
    package-lock.json
    package.json
```

Here's my second project's gulpfile

```
let project_folder = "dist";
let source_folder = "#scr";

let path = {
    build: {
        html: project_folder + "/",
        css: project_folder + "/css/",
        js: project_folder + "/js/",
        img: project_folder + "/img/",
        fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
    },
    src: {
        html: source_folder + "/*.html",
        css: source_folder + "/scss/style.scss",
        js: source_folder + "/js/script.js",
        img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
        fonts: source_folder + "/fonts/*.ttf",
    },
    watch: {
        html: source_folder + "/**/*.html",
        css: source_folder + "/scss/**/*.scss",
        js: source_folder + "/js/**/*.js",
        img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
    },
    clean: "./" + project_folder + "/"
}

let { src, dest } = require('gulp'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();

function browserSync(params) {
    browsersync.init({
        server:{
            baseDir: "./" + project_folder + "/"
        },
        port: 3000,
        notify: false
    })
}

function html() {
    return src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}


let build = gulp.series(html);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, browserSync);

exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

terminal

```
[10:57:21] Using gulpfile ~\YandexDisk\Web\Funiro\gulpfile.js
[10:57:21] Starting 'default'...
[10:57:21] Starting 'browserSync'...
[10:57:21] Starting 'html'...
[10:57:21] Finished 'html' after 31 ms
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.31.89:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./dist/
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?

```
let source_folder = "#scr";
```

Maybe "#src"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please can elaborate a bit more your answer and explain why you may have found the root cause.

Comment: He wrote "#scr" - it's illogical. He obviously meant "#src".

Comment: You are right and I confess I didn't saw it on first read. You could improve your answer by explictly saying there is a typo i.e. : "There is a typo mistake with #scr and #src"